# What does span mean in exponential moving average?

Tags: terminology, exponential-smoothing

To borrow from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) of `pandas`' `ewm` function: the center of mass, span, halflife and alpha of an exponential moving average can be derived from each other when any one (and only one) of them is specified.

While the meanings of center of mass and half-life seem self-explanatory, I have trouble understanding the meaning of span. Certainly, you can express it in terms of the rest of the listed parameters, such as:

$$span = 1-\frac{\alpha}{2}$$
$$span = 2 com-1$$

But the implication of span is not obvious from these expressions. I wonder if its meaning can be explained intuitively?

Comment: Note: This is not an answer. I've been dealing with the  ewma and its variants for over a decade and I've never seen the terms "com" or "span". So, IMHO, I would suggest not worrying about it. As long as you understand $\alpha$ and $halflife$, you should be fine. Also, note that some define the ewma as $\hat{S}_{t+1} = \alpha \hat{S}_{t} + (1-\alpha) X_{t}$ and others define it as $\hat{S}_{t+1} = (1-\alpha) \hat{S}_{t} + \alpha X_{t}$ .So be aware of that because it can get confusing if you define it one way and the literature defines it the other. How it's defined depends on what you read.

Comment: Thanks @mlofton. May I also ask what is actually meant by, for example, a "20-day EWMA"? Does "20-day" carry no meaning except for implying a half-life? Since in no way 20-day EWAM uses only data in the 20-day window.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm not certain but it might mean the following. The $\lambda$ that is equal to $\frac{2}{N+1}$ results in an ewma that is "equivalent" to a N period moving average in terms of weighted age of the data. ( see Robert Brown's Smoothing, Forecasting and Prediction of Discrete Time Series for the details of weighted age ) . So, my best guess is that  $\lambda =  \frac{2}{20 + 1}$ is being used for the ewma so that it's" equivalent" to a 20 day moving average in terms of weighted age. But, you are correct in that an actual ewma should use all the data starting from $t=1$.

Comment: This `N` is exactly the `span`.